# GROUP BY Collapse Dates into CSV separated column

Tags: sql, sqlite

Assuming I had a data-set like the following:

```
╔═══════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ Count ║    Min(Time)     ║    Max(Time)     ║      Domain       ║
╠═══════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║   647 ║ 2021-01-06 13:08 ║ 2021-01-12 16:25 ║ mail.yahoo.com    ║
║   350 ║ 2021-01-06 13:08 ║ 2021-01-12 16:24 ║ mail.google.com   ║
║   133 ║ 2021-01-06 13:08 ║ 2021-01-12 16:28 ║ www.google.com    ║
║    27 ║ 2021-01-06 13:10 ║ 2021-01-12 15:49 ║ t.fluff.com       ║
║    22 ║ 2021-01-06 15:52 ║ 2021-01-12 15:55 ║ www.thethings.com ║
╚═══════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

And a simple GROUP BY statement like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DOMAIN), MIN(TIME), MAX(Time), Domain  
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY DOMAIN 
ORDER BY COUNT(DOMAIN) DESC
```

Is there a way in SQLLite to flatten the Time Column so I could get all Time listed as CSV column from oldest to newest.  Know this is possible in SQL Server and Oracle with XML Path and other fanciness, whats the simplest way to accomplish this that I could run against a simple SQLLite Database.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(DOMAIN), MIN(TIME), MAX(Time), Domain  ,
     Group_concat(time)
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY DOMAIN 
ORDER BY COUNT(DOMAIN) DESC
```

Comment: Wow no such thing as a dumb question but ... My googling is weak this morning thanks !  Will mark answer when I can

Answer (score 1):

SQLite's aggregate function `GROUP_CONCAT()` does not support an `ORDER BY` clause, so you can't have the `Time`s listed from oldest to newest.
But you can do it with `GROUP_CONCAT()` window function:

```
SELECT Domain, counter, min_time, max_time, times
FROM (
  SELECT Domain,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DOMAIN) counter, 
         MIN(TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY DOMAIN) min_time, 
         MAX(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY DOMAIN) max_time,
         GROUP_CONCAT(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY DOMAIN ORDER BY Time DESC) times,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DOMAIN ORDER BY Time) rn
  FROM tablename
)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY counter DESC
```